# Display seconds in formula using date/time

Tags: formula, datetime

How can seconds be displayed in a formula field that references a rollup summary field that calculates the MAX value of datetime field from the child objects?

The rollup summary contains a datetime value, but doesn't display the seconds. It only has the format: `1/21/2020 12:23 AM`. I'd like to display the seconds so it would display like this: `1/13/2020 12:23:03 AM` as an example.

I was attempting to to pull the seconds using some examples I found online:
`VALUE( MID( TEXT( My_Rollup_Time_Field__c - 5 ), 18, 2 ) )`

Comment: use `SECOND` function.

Comment: That just gives me the seconds. I need to format the datetime field so that the seconds display. I tried the following: `TEXT(Month( DATEVALUE(Start_Time__c) ))&"/"& TEXT(Day( DATEVALUE(Start_Time__c) )) & "/" & TEXT(Year( DATEVALUE(Start_Time__c) )) & " " & MID(TEXT(Start_Time__c),12,8)`, which partially works. It is in the 24 hour clock and I need to display in the 12 hour clock.